# Problem with spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have an option menu when pressed it brings in front spinner with two options:

```
    <item>Choose Car</item>

    <item>Search Route</item>
```

When selecting an item it gets me to a different activity.

The first item is always selected so by default when I press the menu item I get to that class!!

Question:

How do I proceed so when I choose the menu item,initially to have no item selected in the  spinner?

Thank u!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another item (none) and add it as the first one. The user would then have to explicitly select one of the other choices:

```
<item>None selected</item>
<item>Choose Car</item>
<item>Search Route</item>
```